# Find the first derivative of given limit

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ is a polynomial satisfying $f(x).f(y)=f(x) + f(y) +f(xy) -2 $  for all x ,y and $f(2)=1025$ , then the value of lim x tending to 2 $f'(x)$ is 
[image: My work]

I want to know that value at $f(1)=1$ can also be predicted or not . I think It must be given that $f(1) $ is not equal to $1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f(x).f(y)=f(x) + f(y) +f(xy) -2\implies f(1)\times f(1)=f(1) + f(1) +f(1) -2$$ So, let $z=f(1)$. Then $$z^2=3z-2$$ Solve the quadratic equation in $z=f(1)$.

Comment: I want to know that how I will find at f(1)=1 , I found the value at f(1)=2

Comment: There are two solutions.

Comment: I know , i want to find limit .